# How to call JavaScript function from table cell in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, tablecell

I have created an Asp Page in which there is one `<asp:Table>` object. The rows I will be generating dynamically from the code behind.

In one of the cells in the table I want to call the JavaScript function. The JavaScript function is: `Vizit.Write("http://path/to/file.ext", { buttons: [ "InstantPreview" ] });`, this line of code will return the control. And the returned control I want to place in the TableCell. To know, what is the actual meaning of this, you can refer [this](http://support.vizit.com/entries/20403587-Vizit-Client-Library) link.

My code is:

```
CheckBox selectImage;
Label lblTitle;
Label lblResolution;
Label lblFileType;
LinkButton lbDownload;

System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow row;
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell cellSelectImage;
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell cellScriptFunction;
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell cellTitle;
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell cellResolution;
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell cellFileType;
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell cellFileDownload;
foreach (SPListItem image in returnedImages)
{
    row = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow();
    cellSelectImage = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell();
    selectImage = new CheckBox();
    cellSelectImage.Controls.Add(selectImage);
    cellScriptFunction = new TableCell(); // in this table cell I want to place the control which is returned from the javascript                                

}
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: did u try registerstartup script

Answer (score 0):

you can include script using `TableCell.Text`

```
  cellScriptFunction = new TableCell(); // in this table cell I want to place the control which is returned from the javascript                                


cellScriptFunction.Text = "<script> Vizit.Write(\"http://path/to/file.ext\", { buttons: [ \"InstantPreview\" ] }); </script>";
```